# How to bind combobox events to viewmodel with ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I am relatively new to MVVM and I want to bind my view to the view model. I have a lot of code to move from the CodeBehind into the ViewModel class.

What I would like to do is binding the ComboBox Events to the corresponding ViewModel ICommand methods. I want the ComboBox to show "CompanyB" when the view loads and when I make a selection, the ComboBox should give me "CompanyA", "CompanyB" and "CompanyC" as options to select from.

After a company was selected, the values of the 2 textboxes below

> Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner
>
> Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail

must change accordingly.

The problem is with my code both the ComboBox and the textboxes remain empty and there is also nothing to choose from inside the combobox.

Could you please help me find what I am missing here? Thanks in advance for any help!

**XAML (neueNachbestellung.xaml):**

```xml
<Window xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,25,0,0" x:Name="leftStPnl">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxEmpfaenger" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Empf}" 
                      Text="{Binding Empfaenger}" 
                      FontSize="12" Width="150" Margin="118,0,0,0"                      
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelValue}">
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfAnsprechpartner" Text="{Binding Empf_Ansprechpartner}" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>    
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfMail" Text="{Binding Empfaenger_Mail}" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="73,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind (neueNachbestellung.xaml.cs):**

```cs
public neueNachbestellung(string someId) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new neueNachbestellungViewModel(someId);
}
```

**View Model(neueNachbestellungViewModel.cs)**:

```cs
public class neueNachbestellungViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public ICommand LoadCombobox => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteLoadCombobox);
public ICommand ComboboxSelectionChanged => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged);
public Nachbestellung Nachbest { get; set; }
private object someObject;
private ObservableCollection<string> _empf;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Empf
        {
            get { return _empf; }
            set
            {
                _empf = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Empf");
            }
        }
        private string _selValue = "12";
        public string SelValue  
        {
            get { return _selValue; }
            set
            {
                _selValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelValue");
            }
        }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

public neueNachbestellungViewModel(string id)
{

    this.Artikel = new ArtikelViewModel();
    this.ArtikelList = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();
    InitializeReorderModel(id);    
    ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged(someObject);                        
}

public void InitializeReorderModel(string id)
{
    //set the MODEL
    this.Nachbest = new Nachbestellung();

    //Retrieve and set some values on *VIEW LOAD*!
    var dbOracle = new Datenbank();
    this.Nachbest.Bv = dbOracle.GetBauvorhaben(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Hv = hv;
    this.Nachbest.Bauleiter = dbOracle.GetBauleiter(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Projektleiter = dbOracle.GetProjektleiter(hv);
}

private void ExecuteLoadCombobox(object param)
{
    Empf = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "CompanyA",
        "CompanyB",
        "CompanyC"         
    };

    //Company B is the standard selection on combobox load                     
    Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyB";
    Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "orders@companyB.com";
}

private void ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged(object param)
{
    Empf = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "CompanyA",
        "CompanyB",
        "CompanyC"             
    };

    switch (SelValue)
    {

        case "CompanyA":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyA";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "service@companyA.com";
            }
            break;

        case "CompanyB":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyB";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "orders@companyB.com";
            }
            break;

        case "CompanyC":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyC";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "info@companyC.com";
            }
            break;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong with the company selection!");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**View Fragment**:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to bind the ComboBox's `SelectionChanged` event when you already have a `SelectedValue` Binding. Why would you trigger a command when the setter of the `SelValue` view model property is already called? Also note that you would usually use SelectedValue in conjunction with SelectedValuePath. Otherwise bind SelectedItem.

Comment: Besides that, when you change the `Empf` property value at runtime, the property must fire a change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This must be done for any property that should trigger a UI update.

Comment: Does that mean I need an Observable class for my view model? And inside the Observable class go the properties that change inside the view model, e.g. Empf?

Comment: Just implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event in the setter of each property that should trigger a UI update. I you search the web for INotifyPropertyChanged, you'll find a bunch of information.

Comment: That is probably what confuses me. I have learned that you don't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface inside the view model but inside a Model class with business logic or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's totally wrong. A view model is the typical place to implement that interface.

Comment: Ok, I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface inside my ViewModel (see original Post edit) and used it on the properties 'Empf' and 'SelValue'. But still no items inside my Combobox and no default values on View Load. What do I need to do to make my combobox set a default value on view load and contain my company items?

Comment: Remove all those `Interaction.Triggers` and call ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged in the view model constructor.

Comment: Your ComboBox also gets the wrong DataContext, since you have `DataContext="{Binding Nachbest}` on its parent StackPanel. Remove that too.

Comment: You may also have a problem setting both `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedValue`. Typically you'd just bind one

Comment: @RobinBennett: I want the default index 12 for my combobox (because this company is the standard selection) when the view loads but I also want the index to change when another item(company) is selected. If I don't use selectedindex="12" how am I supposed to achieve the default setter?

Comment: To get a default, set a default value for `SelectedValue` in the ViewModel. Part of the idea of MVVM is to keep business rules in the ViewModel, where they're easier t find.

Comment: @Clemens: I removed the DataContext in the stack panel and all interaction triggers and called the ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged method in the view model constructor. (see edit in my original post). I also called the method ExecuteLoadComboBox in my view model constructor before the ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged method because I want to select the combobox index 12 to be set when the view loads.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: @RobinBennett: No, the view loads with the default company now and the contact partner and his or her mail address is in the 2 textboxes. Also the List of companies (item source) is working because I can choose from one of these 3 now. But the issue is if I choose one company, the text in the textboxes below it won't get updated! Note that I also want to set the chosen value in all 3 controls (combobox, textbox1,textbox2) to the corresponding member property of the class instance Nachbest! This is why my text binding of these controls is hooked with the view model's property Nachbest.

Comment: The view model is supposed to direct the chosen values to the model Nachbestellung and then they will be saved in my database.

Comment: OK, so rather than attempting to catch an event from the UI, what you should do is put some code in `SelValue.Set` that updates the other properties. The point of this is that you could write a unit test to check that the other properties are updated when a value is selected.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What other properties are you referring to? Empf contains all the companies and SelValue contains the currently selected company. And the ExecuteComboBoxSelectionChanged method must trigger as soon as I have selected another company item. But currently this method is only in the view model's constructor. Doesn't that mean that it is triggered only when the view loads and then it never updates? How do I make the ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged method trigger once my combobox selection has changed?

Comment: I think MY problem here is that this method is never invoked again after the view model's constructor was initialized.This is why I initially bound my combobox in xaml  to this event method with a command binding property.

Comment: I moved the switch case into the SelValue setter and now it is working. Probably a quick and dirty solution but for now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

This is my quick & dirty solution. It does what it needs to and I don't have these click_button, selection_changed events inside my code behind anymore but inside my view model. That is all I need for now. Obviously not an elegant solution but it is working. I hope I can help some developers with it in the future who run into similar problems. Just a side note: The ICommand properties inside the view model are not necessary in this scenario but I am using them to handle button click events in the view. You can replace them with your own properties if you don't need the DelegateCommand class in your application.

**XAML (neueNachbestellung.xaml):**

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,25,0,0" x:Name="leftStPnl">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxEmpfaenger" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Empf}" 
                      Text="{Binding Empfaenger}" 
                      FontSize="12" Width="150" Margin="118,0,0,0"                      
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelValue}">
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfAnsprechpartner" DataContext="{Binding Nachbest}" Text="{Binding Empf_Ansprechpartner}" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>    
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfMail" DataContext="{Binding Nachbest}" Text="{Binding Empfaenger_Mail}" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="73,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind (neueNachbestellung.xaml.cs):**

```
public neueNachbestellung(string someId) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new neueNachbestellungViewModel(someId);
}
```

**neueNachbestellungViewModel.cs:**

```
public class neueNachbestellungViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
//public ICommand LoadCombobox => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteLoadCombobox);
public ICommand ComboboxSelectionChanged => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged);
public Nachbestellung Nachbest { get; set; }
private object someObject; //DelegateCommand.cs requires an argument
private ObservableCollection<string> _empf;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Empf
        {
            get { return _empf; }
            set
            {
                _empf = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Empf");
            }
        }
        private string _selValue = "CompanyB"; //default value
        public string SelValue  
        {
            get { return _selValue; }
            set
            {
                _selValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelValue");
 switch (SelValue)
    {

        case "CompanyA":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyA";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "service@companyA.com";
            }
            break;

        case "CompanyB":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyB";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "orders@companyB.com";
            }
            break;

        case "CompanyC":
            {
                Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyC";
                Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "info@companyC.com";
            }
            break;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong with the company selection!");
            break;
    }
//setting the Empfaenger property here with the current selected value is necessary for the database insert later on!
Nachbest.Empfaenger = SelValue;
            }
        }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

public neueNachbestellungViewModel(string id)
{

    this.Artikel = new ArtikelViewModel();
    this.ArtikelList = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();
    InitializeReorderModel(id);    
    ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged(someObject);                        
}

public void InitializeReorderModel(string id)
{
    //set the MODEL
    this.Nachbest = new Nachbestellung();

    //Retrieve and set some values on *VIEW LOAD*!
    var dbOracle = new Datenbank();
    this.Nachbest.Bv = dbOracle.GetBauvorhaben(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Hv = hv;
    this.Nachbest.Bauleiter = dbOracle.GetBauleiter(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Projektleiter = dbOracle.GetProjektleiter(hv);
}

private void ExecuteComboboxSelectionChanged(object param)
{
    Empf = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "CompanyA",
        "CompanyB",
        "CompanyC"             
    };
Nachbest.Empf_Ansprechpartner = "CompanyB";
            Nachbest.Empfaenger_Mail = "orders@companyB.com";
            Nachbest.Empfaenger = SelValue; //if this is left out and there is no selection (just the default remaining unchanged!), Nachbest.Empfaenger will be null!
}
}
```